# Convert multiline string to single line in java

Tags: java, groovy, scriptrunner-for-jira

I want to convert a markdown table to a json string using Scriptrunner for Jira Server (Java/Groovy).

The table is stored in the description field of the issue and looks something like this when displaying the issue through the rest api /rest/api/2/issue

```json
"description": "|| ||Due Date||Done on||OK/NOK||Remarks||\r\n|*Task 1*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 2*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 3*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 4*| 15/03/23| | | See document X|"
```

For clarity, this is what the table looks like in interpreted MD:

|  | Due Date | Done on | OK/NOK | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Task 1** |  |  |  |  |
| **Task 2** |  |  |  |  |
| **Task 3** |  |  |  |  |
| **Task 4** | 15/03/23 |  |  | See document X |

This to be converted in the following Json (with a block for each line)

```json
{
    "ACTION": [{
            "DONE ON": "",
            "DUE DATE": "15/03/23",
            "NOTE": "See document X",
            "TITLE": "Task 4"
        }
         
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have already figured out the regular expression to be used: https://regex101.com/r/Ph5f0a/1

Note that the table is always going to be the same, same number of lines and columns with this specific formatting.

---

Thing is when I display the content of the issue's description, the \r\n are interpreted as newlines.

**Is there a way to display the content as a single line "raw" string so that my regex could work?**

Here is the code snippet I used for now.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import java.io.IOException
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import groovy.json.*
import org.apache.log4j.Level

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

log.setLevel(Level.INFO);

def issue = issueManager.getIssueObject('PTIJ-68')

def description_raw = issue.getDescription()

log.info("issue.getDescription() = ${issue.getDescription().toString()}")
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a regex that ignores newlines (like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dbZAEu/1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simplistic regex with CSV handling:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

String description = "|| ||Due Date||Done on||OK/NOK||Remarks||\r\n|*Task 1*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 2*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 3*| | | | |\r\n|*Task 4*| 15/03/23| | | See document X|" 

List data = []

description.splitEachLine( /\*?\|+\*?/ ){ _, title, dueDate, doneOn, ok_nok, remarks ->
  data << [ 'TTILE':title, "DUE DATE":dueDate.trim(), "DONE ON":doneOn.trim(), "NOTE":remarks.trim() ]
}

data.remove 0 // skip the head

JsonOutput.prettyPrint JsonOutput.toJson( ACTION:data )
```

prints:

```
{
    "ACTION": [
        {
            "TTILE": "Task 1",
            "DUE DATE": "",
            "DONE ON": "",
            "NOTE": ""
        },
        {
            "TTILE": "Task 2",
            "DUE DATE": "",
            "DONE ON": "",
            "NOTE": ""
        },
        {
            "TTILE": "Task 3",
            "DUE DATE": "",
            "DONE ON": "",
            "NOTE": ""
        },
        {
            "TTILE": "Task 4",
            "DUE DATE": "15/03/23",
            "DONE ON": "",
            "NOTE": "See document X"
        }
    ]
}
```